# What are these creatures in Shang-Chi?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, magical-creatures, mythology, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

*Shang-Chi: Legend of the 10 Rings* features a [variety of classical Chinese mythical creatures](https://www.cbr.com/every-mythological-creature-shang-chi/). However I did not recognise the antagonist "soul sucker" creatures.

I have no example images, but they resemble (ethereal) tentacled bat demons. Are they based off of authentic creatures from Chinese mythology? If so, what is their inspiration?

Answer (score 3):

They come not from Chinese mythology but from Marvel Comics. They are the spawn of the [Dweller-in-Darkness](https://www.marvel.com/characters/dweller-in-darkness), who was first seen in *Doctor Strange* #30.

[image: Image of Dweller-in-Darkness confronting Dr. Strange]

The director identified the character in an interview with *[Indiewire](https://www.indiewire.com/2021/09/shang-chi-and-the-ten-rings-marvel-visual-effects-1234665539/)*.

> We wanted to make sure that the Great Protector represented peace and tranquility and the Dweller in Darkness — which I don’t even consider a dragon — was the manifestation of evil